# Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename' when connecting to local sql db with function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, azure-functions

I created serverless function which I want to connect to my local SQL Server database. In the local.setting.json I added the connection string that works ok when I try to connect with web api:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "MyConnectionString": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=UsersServiceContext; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|UsersServiceContext.mdf"
  }
}
```

Then in my function I try to connect:

```
var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyConnectionString");

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
{
    conn.Open();
    //do something
}
```

But when I make the request I get the following error:

> Exception while executing function: Function1. System.Data.SqlClient: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

I'm not sure what exactly could be the problem since it works ok when I try to connect with web api.

Comment: ; at the end maybe

Comment: sadly no, still the same error

Comment: add the database name Database=dbname;